# Why does the text "Erase process has failed." Keep on popping up when I try to delete a ISO Image(I tried using terminal and it didn't work

Tags: macos, disk-utility, storage

[image]
This is the screenshot that i have taken what should i do to delete this container?

Comment: A container is not an ISO image. What terminal commands did you use?

Comment: Also, what is shown in "Show Details"?

Comment: Container Disk 1 usually contains a volume called "Macintosh HD," not something you want to delete. Also go to the "View" menu and select  "Show all devices" which will show what is **in** those containers.